# Spark StringIndexer returning empty dataset

Tags: java, apache-spark

Apache Spark StringIndexerModel is returning an empty dataset after transform on one particular column. I am using Adult dataset: http://mlr.cs.umass.edu/ml/datasets/Adult

Step 1: Create StringIndexerModel and save it locally

```
StringIndexerModel model = new StringIndexer().setInputCol(column).setOutputCol("label").setHandleInvalid("skip").setStringOrderType("alphabetAsc").fit(originalDataset);
model.write().save(filelocation);
```

Step 2: Read indexer model and transform the new dataset

```
StringIndexerModel model = StringIndexerModel.read().load(filelocation);
newDataset = model.transform(newDataset).drop(column).withColumnRenamed("label", column);
```

New Dataset:

```
+---+------------+------------+----------+-------------+------+--------------+-------------------+--------------+----------------+-----+--------------+----+-----------------+
|age|capital gain|capital loss|education |education num|fnlgwt|hours per week|marital status     |native country|occupation      |race |relationship  |sex |workclass        |
+---+------------+------------+----------+-------------+------+--------------+-------------------+--------------+----------------+-----+--------------+----+-----------------+
|39 |2174        |0           | Bachelors|13           |77516 |40            | Never-married     | United-States| Adm-clerical   |White| Not-in-family|Male| State-gov       |
|50 |0           |0           | Bachelors|13           |83311 |13            | Married-civ-spouse| United-States| Exec-managerial|White| Husband      |Male| Self-emp-not-inc|
+---+------------+------------+----------+-------------+------+--------------+-------------------+--------------+----------------+-----+--------------+----+-----------------+
```

Correct Output:

```
Column: education | File Location: localFolder/stringIndex/education
Labels: [ 10th,  11th,  12th,  1st-4th,  5th-6th,  7th-8th,  9th,  Assoc-acdm,  Assoc-voc,  Bachelors,  Doctorate,  HS-grad,  Masters,  Preschool,  Prof-school,  Some-college]
+---+------------+------------+-------------+------+--------------+-------------------+--------------+----------------+-----+--------------+----+-----------------+---------+
|age|capital gain|capital loss|education num|fnlgwt|hours per week|marital status     |native country|occupation      |race |relationship  |sex |workclass        |education|
+---+------------+------------+-------------+------+--------------+-------------------+--------------+----------------+-----+--------------+----+-----------------+---------+
|39 |2174        |0           |13           |77516 |40            | Never-married     | United-States| Adm-clerical   |White| Not-in-family|Male| State-gov       |9.0      |
|50 |0           |0           |13           |83311 |13            | Married-civ-spouse| United-States| Exec-managerial|White| Husband      |Male| Self-emp-not-inc|9.0      |
+---+------------+------------+-------------+------+--------------+-------------------+--------------+----------------+-----+--------------+----+-----------------+---------+

Column: marital status | File Location: localFolder/stringIndex/marital status
Labels: [ Divorced,  Married-AF-spouse,  Married-civ-spouse,  Married-spouse-absent,  Never-married,  Separated,  Widowed]
+---+------------+------------+-------------+------+--------------+--------------+----------------+-----+--------------+----+-----------------+---------+--------------+
|age|capital gain|capital loss|education num|fnlgwt|hours per week|native country|occupation      |race |relationship  |sex |workclass        |education|marital status|
+---+------------+------------+-------------+------+--------------+--------------+----------------+-----+--------------+----+-----------------+---------+--------------+
|39 |2174        |0           |13           |77516 |40            | United-States| Adm-clerical   |White| Not-in-family|Male| State-gov       |9.0      |4.0           |
|50 |0           |0           |13           |83311 |13            | United-States| Exec-managerial|White| Husband      |Male| Self-emp-not-inc|9.0      |2.0           |
+---+------------+------------+-------------+------+--------------+--------------+----------------+-----+--------------+----+-----------------+---------+--------------+

Column: native country | File Location: localFolder/stringIndex/native country
Labels: [ ?,  Cambodia,  Canada,  China,  Columbia,  Cuba,  Dominican-Republic,  Ecuador,  El-Salvador,  England,  France,  Germany,  Greece,  Guatemala,  Haiti,  Holand-Netherlands,  Honduras,  Hong,  Hungary,  India,  Iran,  Ireland,  Italy,  Jamaica,  Japan,  Laos,  Mexico,  Nicaragua,  Outlying-US(Guam-USVI-etc),  Peru,  Philippines,  Poland,  Portugal,  Puerto-Rico,  Scotland,  South,  Taiwan,  Thailand,  Trinadad&Tobago,  United-States,  Vietnam,  Yugoslavia]
+---+------------+------------+-------------+------+--------------+----------------+-----+--------------+----+-----------------+---------+--------------+--------------+
|age|capital gain|capital loss|education num|fnlgwt|hours per week|occupation      |race |relationship  |sex |workclass        |education|marital status|native country|
+---+------------+------------+-------------+------+--------------+----------------+-----+--------------+----+-----------------+---------+--------------+--------------+
|39 |2174        |0           |13           |77516 |40            | Adm-clerical   |White| Not-in-family|Male| State-gov       |9.0      |4.0           |39.0          |
|50 |0           |0           |13           |83311 |13            | Exec-managerial|White| Husband      |Male| Self-emp-not-inc|9.0      |2.0           |39.0          |
+---+------------+------------+-------------+------+--------------+----------------+-----+--------------+----+-----------------+---------+--------------+--------------+

Column: occupation | File Location: localFolder/stringIndex/occupation
Labels: [ ?,  Adm-clerical,  Armed-Forces,  Craft-repair,  Exec-managerial,  Farming-fishing,  Handlers-cleaners,  Machine-op-inspct,  Other-service,  Priv-house-serv,  Prof-specialty,  Protective-serv,  Sales,  Tech-support,  Transport-moving]
+---+------------+------------+-------------+------+--------------+-----+--------------+----+-----------------+---------+--------------+--------------+----------+
|age|capital gain|capital loss|education num|fnlgwt|hours per week|race |relationship  |sex |workclass        |education|marital status|native country|occupation|
+---+------------+------------+-------------+------+--------------+-----+--------------+----+-----------------+---------+--------------+--------------+----------+
|39 |2174        |0           |13           |77516 |40            |White| Not-in-family|Male| State-gov       |9.0      |4.0           |39.0          |1.0       |
|50 |0           |0           |13           |83311 |13            |White| Husband      |Male| Self-emp-not-inc|9.0      |2.0           |39.0          |4.0       |
+---+------------+------------+-------------+------+--------------+-----+--------------+----+-----------------+---------+--------------+--------------+----------+
```

Wrong output: All other models are working correctly except this one

```
Column: race | File Location: localFolder/stringIndex/race
Labels: [ Amer-Indian-Eskimo,  Asian-Pac-Islander,  Black,  Other,  White]
+---+------------+------------+-------------+------+--------------+------------+---+---------+---------+--------------+--------------+----------+----+
|age|capital gain|capital loss|education num|fnlgwt|hours per week|relationship|sex|workclass|education|marital status|native country|occupation|race|
+---+------------+------------+-------------+------+--------------+------------+---+---------+---------+--------------+--------------+----------+----+
+---+------------+------------+-------------+------+--------------+------------+---+---------+---------+--------------+--------------+----------+----+
```

I would really appreciate any help in fixing this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the new dataset had incorrect data. Whitespace is expected before the value.

Adding whitespace `' White'` got me the correct output.